# Stacking math books

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose that I have $6$ different books, $2$ of which are math books. In how many ways can I stack my $6$ books on a shelf if I do not want the math books to be next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $6! = 720$ ways to stack the books without any restrictions. We can subtract away the number of ways with the two math books next to each other to yield our answer.

Imagine the two books together as one. Then, there are $5!$ arrangements with the books together. However, since there are two books, there are really $2 \times 5!$ arrangements.

Thus, the answer is

$6! - 2 * 5! = 720 - 240 = 480$.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the $6!$ orders in which to stack six books, precisely $2\times 5!$ of those orders have the two math books consecutive. To see this, consider the two math books glued together, in one of $2$ orders, to form a single book. That reduces the "number" of items being ordered to $5$.